# On nilpotent singular $\mathbb F_2^{n\times n}$ matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, permutations, extremal-combinatorics, nilpotent-matrices

Let $M$ be a $0/1$ matrix over $\mathbb F_2^{n\times n}$ with determinant $0$.

The set of such singular matrices form a semigroup.

<s>The set of nilpotent matrices of size $n\times n$ form a semigroup.</s>

1. Are there always permutations $P,Q$ such that $PMQ$ is nilpotent?
2. How many permutations $P,Q$ are always there such that $PMQ$ is nilpotent?
3. If $T$ is nilpotent, there is always a $k\leq n$ such that there is always a row or column with all $0$s in $T^k$. What is a tight upper bound on $k$ as a function of $n$ that works for all nilpotent matrices in $\mathbb F_2^{n\times n}$?
4. <s>Are there always permutations $P,Q$ such that $(PMQ)^2$ contains a $0$ row or a $0$ column?</s>

Comment: $M=\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&0\cr}$ has determinant zero, but there are no permutations $P,Q$ such that $PMQ$ is nilpotent.

Comment: I think it is called index when the matrix vanishes valnishes. There is no nomenclature for the $k$ introduced.

Comment: The nilpotent elements do not form a subsemigroup.  Take  E_12 E_21=E_11

Comment: The answer to 4 is no.  If n is odd let M be the all ones matrix.

Comment: If n is a power of 2 the answer to 3 is k=n. Take I+P where P is the permutation matrix of order 2^n corresponding to the cyclic permutation (1,2,...,n)

Comment: Sorry, in my last comment I meant of order n which is a power of 2